# spring 3.0.1.RELEASE-A compatibility with 3.0.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring

I have to replace the spring 3.0.1.RELEASE with spring 3.0.1.RELEASE-A.Iwould like to have some key points on the version change and compatibility. Please help me

Comment: why don't you see the official site?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's real, real old version of framework, month ago v4.0 was released. I really advise you to upgrade to v3.2.4 or 4.0 if you can. About changelog: look at this
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/changelog.txt

Answer (score 0):

3.0.1.A is the same version with a fixed OSGi manifest. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

They're both identical, besides some changes in the OSGI manifests.

See the update section in [the official blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2010/02/18/spring-framework-3-0-1-released) and compare [both versions on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/compare/v3.0.1.RELEASE...v3.0.1.RELEASE-A)!

Comment: I wonder if it worth to check the existing answers before adding your own, identical to the existing one?